# Html and Css that I created outside ASP.NET doesn't fit when I add it in ASP.NET CORE Razor

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created the html and css for My Profile page and when I added that html and css in ASP.NET CORE it looks different.

This is how it looks when I open it from index.html

[image]

And when I added it in ASP cshtml along with styles.css

[image]

Some differences in cshtml:

1. Save Changes button is not exactly where it should be
2. The Dashboard header is center aligned
3. Dashboard boxes are in different places and different widths(I used bootstrap row and columns to fit them)
4. There is no space between Login Details,Dashboard and Reservations

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Have in mind that .NET page is using a `_Layout.cshtml` which has the `<html><body>` content. When you copy the html, make sure you get only what is inside the `<body />` tag

Comment: you may lack some CSS when integrating your code in Razor. This is again not an issue of asp.net core or razor. Try inspecting your output (rendered) html to find out what's wrong. Usually that's how we solve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I had an reference to an different bootstrap version library in the layout file.

This one: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />`

and the version of bootstrap I used for my html was 5.0.0, so I just removed the reference to bootstrap in layout and I added the new one:
`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  crossorigin="anonymous">`

It's working now.